# "while loop" inside a "for loop" to shuffle array (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, while-loop

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR TIME!

```
function shuffleDeck()
{

    var chosenCard:int = 0;

    trace("DECK LENGTH " + deck.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
    {
        chosenCard = int(Math.random() * deck.length);

        while (shuffledDeck[chosenCard] != null)
        {

            chosenCard = int(Math.random() * deck.length);

        }

        shuffledDeck[chosenCard] = deck[i];
        trace(shuffledDeck[chosenCard]);
        if (shuffledDeck.length == deck.length)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    trace(shuffledDeck);

} //End ShuffleDeck
```

If I remove the if statement calling the break, the program will hang and get stuck. Which I don't understand... You can see below that the shuffling process is a mess, and for some reason the shuffled deck gets "blanks".... **What's worse**, is the shuffle() function is somehow getting called TWICE, event though I remove the eventlistener, and cannot find any other place it is being called from ---  **Trace Statements BELOW**

```
Shuffling Now
DECK LENGTH 7
1 
2
3
4
5
3,1,,,2,4,5
Shuffling Now
DECK LENGTH 7
1 
3,1,1,,2,4,5

**EDIT**

Shuffling Now
DECK LENGTH 7
DECK: 37,38,39,40,41,42,43
Shuffled Deck: 38,37,,41,39,40,42
Shuffling Now
DECK LENGTH 7
DECK: 37,38,39,40,41,42,43
Shuffled Deck: 38,37,37,41,39,40,42
```

AS you can see, I trace the deck.length and then the deck Array itself. Then the shuffledDeck Array. The first time through it ignores the last element, then the function repeats (DON'T KNOW WHY) and inserts a 37 in shuffledDeck[1] and [2].

Run again choosing different cards.

```
DECK LENGTH 7
DECK: 41,42,43,44,45,46,47
Shuffled Deck: ,,,,,41,42
Shuffling Now
DECK LENGTH 7
DECK: 41,42,43,44,45,46,47
Shuffled Deck: ,,41,,,41,42
```

Without the if statement causing the break;

```
Shuffling Now
DECK LENGTH 7
DECK: 1,2,3,9,10,11,18
Shuffled Deck: ,,1
Shuffled Deck: ,2,1
Shuffled Deck: ,2,1,,3
Shuffled Deck: 9,2,1,,3
Shuffled Deck: 9,2,1,10,3
Shuffled Deck: 9,2,1,10,3,,11
Shuffled Deck: 9,2,1,10,3,18,11
```

So here: It does exactly what I want (sort of), but HANGS(freezes).

Comment: I should note: The deck Array contains integers. So the output of shuffledDeck[2] might be an actual 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to randomize the order a different way. Instead of having a while loop in the for loop, use a single while loop and an array slice.

- Create a temporary array that is empty
- loop while card array is greater than 0
- pick a random value between 0 and card array length
- slice the card array, removing the random value, and insert it into your temporary array
- the card array will be one card shorter, this will repeat until the card array is empty

here is an article discussing this and other techniques for sorting:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-randomly-shuffle-an-array-in-as3--active-8776